# Cloud Firestore Rules : What is wrong with these rules for a multi-user access based on roles

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have an events collection and users collection. There are 2 types of users. Admin and Standard. Standard users have an admn as their parent. For every event in the events colection, I need to give permission to read,write,update or delete either if he is an admin for that event or standard user for that event.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

   function isAdminForEvent() {
        return request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid;
   }
   function isStandardUserForEvent() {
   return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.parent_uid == resource.data.uid;
   }
    match /events/{eventID}/{document=**} {
      allow read,create,update,delete: if isAdminForEvent() || isStandardUserForEvent();
    }

    match /users/{userID} {
        allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

The simulator works fine, but on a real device, only reading is allowed. Neither a standard user nor an admin is able to do write operations.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the minimum code with which you get the problem. Be sure to log any variables that are relevant (such as the UID and the value of `parent_uid`), and include the output of that logging in your question too.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that if your rules result in an exception, then the entire operation will be rejected.

Also note that `resource.data` is the data *before* a write and `request.resource.data` is the data *after* a write.

```
function isStandardUserForEvent() {
  return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid))
      && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.parent_uid == resource.data.uid;
}

match /events/{eventID}/{document=**} {
  allow read,update,delete: if isAdminForEvent() || isStandardUserForEvent();
  allow create: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.uid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but after changing my rules to the one you provided, I'm not able to see 'My events" page. It automatically logs me off as soon as i login. Also, as a side note, the events collection has 2 subcollections - guests and transactions apart from the usual fields describing the event.